# Line endings from Youtube text

Tags: microsoft-word, youtube

There is a very mysterious event that I can not solve when copying and pasting some block of text.
Maybe, someone could explain what happens here.

Every time I copy a content area from a Youtube video (description field) and paste it to a Microsoft Word document, text comes without CR/LF characters.
I mean, all the text is placed as it was just only one line.
Try yourself and see it.

But, if I paste the block of text to an UltraEdit (text editor) document, all the Carriage Return and Line Feed characters are placed as expected and correctly.

Because UltraEdit cannot see the hyperlinks inside the text, but Word can, I have no clue how to integrate a solution to get CR/LF characters and hyperlinks.

If I use Word, I got no line feeds.

If I use UltraEdit, I end up without hyperlinks.

Anyone has an idea for solve that puzzle?

And could explain what is going on with CR/LF characters from Youtube text?

---

After a while looking for a solution, for my big surprise, that very old Windows 98 text editor, called Write.exe could do the trick.
But it's still failing to get hyperlinks from video timecode. It just catches them from links with "http" prefix.

I tried too many online text editors, GoogleDocs, Office 365, Zoho, EditPad and others. None of them place correctly line endings. But grab hyperlinks.

So, I'm still without a full solution.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/50283-line-endings-youtube-text.html.    Please review A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.

Comment: Also at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/line-endings-from-youtube-text/m-p/3720992/highlight/false#M5704

Comment: I understand and agree with all reasons for don't cross-posting.

My question came up some days ago, and I post it at UltraEdit forum last wednesday.
Mofi, its Moderator, gave me some explanations about Windows clipboard, but couldn't see a solution for that.
And more: he said that UltraEdit forum wasn't a place to discuss that issue. Thus, he deleted the entire thread I had started.

I hope someone has a suggestion that can solve the problem.

I'd like to say sorry if my cross-posting can have harmed this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to duplicate your problem, and I have a solution.

On the Home pane, click the down-arrow for "Paste" and select
"Paste Special...". Select the format of "Unformatted Unicode Text"
and click OK. For me this preserved the line-endings.

I think that the text was copied with the HTML format, but Word by default does
a Text paste, destroying some of the HTML in the clipboard.
Using the above option forces it to process the HTML itself.

Comment: your suggestion works fine for line endings issue. But it solves a half of the problem, because I end up without hyperlinks. Question is how to get correct line endings AND all hyperlinks, including those from video timecodes.